# How to interrupt an animation and transition to another?

Tags: javascript, animation, platformer

I am trying to make a 2D platform game which is Megaman-style. I have some problems when I make shooting animation. In Megaman game, the animation can interrupt by press keys. Just like this:

[image]

For instance, when move button was pressed, the animation frame will loop in D0~D9, if fire button was pressed, it interrupts the current animation and transition to shooting animation(A,B,C). If stop shooting, it goes back to move(D).

I have no idea how to design "interrupt/transition animation system" in my game. 
Here is my pseudo code(JavaScript):

```
animation.play('move',[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],loop);

if(isMoving && key['fire']) {
    //I don't know how to make this work
    animation.play('fire',[A1,A2,B3,B4,B5,C6,D7]);
}
```

and each frame has a metaData like this:

```
{x:37,y:0,w:36,h:41,offsetX:0,offsetY:0,duration:100,collisionBox:[0.4,0,0.84,1.875],
    interrupt:{
        nextMotion:'A',
        nextFrame:7
    }
}
```

What is common solution in this scene? Please, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to use a queue. Like this:

```
queue.push(function() {
    animation.play('fire',[A1,A2,B3,B4,B5,C6,D7]);
    queue.pop()
});
if(isMoving && key['fire']) {
    queue.push(function() {
        animation.play('fire',[A1,A2,B3,B4,B5,C6,D7]);
        queue.pop()
    });
}
```